# How to simplify my CSS stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to simplify my css selector in CSS sheet

I have something like

```
.table_test .div, .table_name .div, .table_company .div{
    color:black;
}


.table_test .div table input, .table_name .div table input{
    color:red;
}
```

My html is something like

```
<div class='table_test'>
  <div class='div'>......
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><input>...</td> 
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class='table_name'>
  <div class='div'>......
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><input>...</td> 
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I feel like there are so many selectors clustered together and was wondering if there is a way to make it simpler. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

**Don't use generic class names** like `div`. There's already an element element called `div`. If you want to target it based on nesting, do so using CSS.

```
.table_name > div {} /* or .table_name div */
```

And not...

```
.table_name .div {}
```

**Use specific selectors.** Is there a reason why you need to go through `table_name .div table input`? Why not target the input specifically by giving it a class?

```
<input class="my_input">
```

And then:

```
.my_input {
  color: red;
}
```

Finally, it's up to you what style to use, but most people tend to use double quotes around html attributes. For example:

`<div class="table_name">` and not `<div class='table_name'>`

Comment: Double quotes or single, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I suppose that's true, but it does make a difference when you need single quotes inside attributes; as part of the title text, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class name that tables that are the same style would share

CSS

```
.similar-table .div{
    color:black;
}


.similar-table input{
    color:red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='table_test similar-table'>
  <div class='div'>......
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><input>...</td> 
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class='table_name similar-table'>
  <div class='div'>......
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><input>...</td> 
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### CSS:

```
.red{
  color:red;
}
.black{
  color:black;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<div class='table_test'>
 <div class='div'>......
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="black">...</td> 
   </tr>
 </table>
</div>

<div class='table_name'>
 <div class='div'>......
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="red">...</td> 
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The best part? This CSS will work [wherever you need it to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Class names like `red` and `float-left` defeat the point of CSS a little. I have definitely seen people do stuff like `.blue-text {color:black !important}` and other such nonsense.

Comment: That may be, but these were example class names not intended for actual use. I presumed the OP's `.div` was the same. At least I hope it was...